# How to create a unit test project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have experience with Visual Studio but very new to Eclipse. In Visual studio, you can easily create a unit test project for an existing production project. In this way, test code and production code are in separate places.

How can I do this in Eclipse? Didn't see a Unit Test project in the New wizard dialog.

Answer (score 1):

File -> New -> JUnit Test Case

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Java development common practices, instead of creating a separate project for unit tests, we usually put unit tests together with the project itself.  Unit tests are normally put under a separate directory so it can be easily compiled and run, and be excluded when creating the final artifact.

Apart from `File -> New -> Junit test case` mentioned in another answer, there are other way to create new tests, for example, by right-clicking the class that you want to test against.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a good practice to put production code and test code together?

Comment: Yes it is. And note that: 1) test code is usually in a separate directory (of same project) and 2) test code is not present in the final artifact.